# What's meaning of badges?

Tags: support

When I am checking my profile in Drupal Answers meta, its showing me only 4 badges in top of the page and If I am checking my profile in Drupal Answers, its showing me 12 badges, while the points are same on both site.

Why there is difference in number of badges in these two sites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While reputation has no meaning on meta sites (it's inherited from the main site and up/downvotes here have no effect on it), badges can be earned independently for either site.

The badges you see in your meta profile have been specifically earned for activity on this site, and those you see in your main profile have been earned for activity on the main site.

Comment: But why points are same in both site?

Comment: Among other things, it's so users can use upvotes and downvotes to signal their approval or disapproval of a topic or feature that's under discussion on the meta site. If such a thing affected people's reputation on the main site, they might be less inclined to get involved. And we want people to get involved :) It's a bit old but here's a [network-wide question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66412/why-is-the-meta-reputation-derived-directly-from-the-parent-site) on the same thing

Comment: Thanks for your quick clarification.